# permission denied error on OSX

Tags: python, macos, pip, permission-denied, easy-install

I have a question about solving the following issue:

> Permission denied:
>   '/Users/ali/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/easy-install.pth'

How can solve the permission denied error in Mac? I am not able also use pip.

Comment: What are you running?

Comment: Update : conda install jsonschema solve the issue.